# Sorting array of formatted time strings

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort my arraylist.

The array list consists of data in time format.

Array:

```
9:15 AM, 10:20 AM
```

How should I sort it?

The result i get from below code is :

```
10:20 AM
9:15 AM
```

Below is my code:

```
String timeText = readFileTime.ReadLine();
    timeSplit = timeText.Split(new char[] { '^' });
    Array.Sort(timeSplit);

foreach (var sortedArray in timeSplit)
    {
        sortedTimeListBox.Items.Add(sortedArray);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to consider converting the values into a proper DateTime structure and utilizing the DateTime.Compare.  See http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-datetime for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Array.Sort(timeSplit, delegate(string first, string second)
{
    return DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(first), Convert.ToDateTime(second));
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, since you simply split a string, you're merely sorting an array of *strings* (meaning `1` comes before `9` and it doesn't care about the decimal point).  To get the sorting you desire, you need to first convert it into a `DateTime` like this:

```
timeSplit = timeText
    .Split(new char[] { '^' });
    .Select(x => new { Time = DateTime.Parse(x), String = x })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Time)
    .Select(x => x.String)
    .ToArray();
```

Here, what we've done is:

1. Split the string as you had done before
2. Create a new anonymous type that contains the original string and also that string converted into a `DateTime`.
3. Ordered it by the `DateTime` property
4. `Select`'ed back to the original string
5. Converted it into an array

`timeSplit` now contains the strings sorted as you wanted.